# Dont have a comma on the last iteration of an each loop in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to print out a list of links separated by commas in Rails.

Heres what I've got:

```
<%= topics.each do |topic| %>
   <a href="<%= topic.link %>" ><%= topic.name %></a>
   ,
<% end %>
```

Heres what I want:

```
<a href="thing_a">Thing A</a>, 
<a href="thing_b">Thing B</a>,
<a href="thing_c">Thing C</a>
```

But right now I get an extra comma on the last iteration of the loop! What should I do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way of doing this is with `map` then [`Array#join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-join):

```
<%= topics.map { |topic| link_to(topic.name, topic.link) }.join(',').html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 5):

if you want to do minimum possible change to your code, you can use the following

```
<%= topics.each do |topic| %>
  <a href="<%= topic.link %>" ><%= topic.name %></a>
     <% if(topic != topics.last) %>
     ,
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: is order guaranteed in this way?

Comment: @DonnyP Yes, as the iteration is being handled by each iterator which guarantees order in Arrays

Answer (score 3):

How about using [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index), and only put comma before the content unless it's not the first item.

```
<% topics.each_with_index do |topic, i| %>
   <% if i > 0 %>
   ,
   <% end %>
   <a href="<%= topic.link %>"><%= topic.name %></a>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @User089247, This code is not to print comma before (not after) the first. See this: http://ideone.com/ADAFQX

Answer (score 1):

I made it in one line call (for active records collections) using the `concat` helper:

```
<% concat (',') if e.bills.last != b %>
```

[`concat` is an ERB helper (TextHelper)](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/concat) to add some HTML without the `<%= %>` syntax, helpful to add few characters.

Here is the full code to make it clear:

```
<% event.bills.each do |b| %>
   <%= link_to(b.number.to_s, bill_display_path(b)) %>
   <% concat (',') if e.bills.last != b %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this. It works for me

```
<%= topics.map{|p| p.topic.name}.join(",") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to print out the comma for all items except for the last:

```
<% topics.each do |topic| %>
  <%= topic %>
  <%= "," if topic != topics.last %>
<% end %>
```

This will check if the current item in the loop is the last item, and will use the `<%= %>` syntax to output the comma.